# Expand debugging output in chrome like in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, web-deployment, firefox-developer-tools

Short question.
I love Firefox Developer Edition but since Chrome has the higher market share I thought of using both or some day maybe even switch to Chrome. Thing is, I'm missing a critical feature in Chrome Devtools.
When I use console.log to debug something in Firefox I get this nice output which I can expand to see all the fancy stuff like childnodes, textContent, etc. as seen in the image below.
So the question is: Has Chrome something similar and if so, how to activate it?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: `dir(yourElement)`

Comment: Could to add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities

Comment: Thank you. Got it. Unfortunately it's nothing that can be activated permanently, which is a bit annoying.

Comment: Technically this is possible by writing a `custom formatter` but I never did it so look for more info yourself.